# SDL2: IMG_Load() - Segmentation fault on Raspberry Pi

Tags: c, arm, raspberry-pi3, sdl-2, sdl-image

This simple code that perfectly works on Ubuntu crashes with a segmentation fault on my Raspberry Pi v3:

```
#include "SDL2/SDL.h"
#include "SDL2/SDL_image.h"

int main()
{
    char* artworkPath = "./testfile.png";

    if (SDL_InitSubSystem(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0)
    {
        SDL_Log("SDL fails to initialize video subsystem!\n%s", SDL_GetError());
        return -1;
    }
    else
        printf("SDL correctly initialized!\n");

    if((IMG_Init(IMG_INIT_PNG)&IMG_INIT_PNG) != IMG_INIT_PNG)
        printf("IMG_Init: %s\n", IMG_GetError());
    else
        printf("Fine!\n");

    SDL_Surface* artworkSurface = IMG_Load(artworkPath);

    if (artworkSurface == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error on loading PNG image\n");
        return -1;
    }
    else
        return 0;
}
```

**Error on loading PNG image** is never shown because it crashes during loading with a segmentation fault, any idea?

Comment: You should probably check that `IMG_Init` succeeded.

Comment: Just a guess, check if `./testfile.png` is actually a valid PNG file.

Comment: Changed opening example code, IMG_Init works fine (Fine! is printed). PNG is valid otherwise it doesn't work on Ubuntu

Comment: Ok, I found the difference between the systems. In Ubuntu (not ARM) there is libpng 1.6.34 and it works. In Raspberry Pi v1 there is libpng 1.6.36, it shows errors regarding IHDR data (not loading the image) but it doesn't crash. On Raspberry Pi v3 there is libpng 1.2.50 and it crashes with a segmentation fault

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

There are bugs on libpng 1.2.50 and 1.6.36 that prevent to correctly load the image.

SDL Image library installs its own dependencies of such library, the correct/only way to use SDL Image on Raspberry Pi is to compile libpng and SDL library from source.

So, download *libpng16* (from GitHub) and *SDL2_image-2.0.5* (from official site) source code, compile (libpng as first) and install them. In this way you'll find on your system libpng 1.6.38.git that doesn't have this problem